# Is there a way that I can get and combine all contents, metadata of hundreds of excel sheets and paste into one?

Tags: excel, metadata, text-mining

So I have 4,000 spreadsheets that contains data arranged with the same set of columns inside. Instead of opening each spreadsheet, copying all data and combine into one spreasheet. Is there a faster way to do it? I tried it in wordstat and ASAP utilities but it doesnt have that feature.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query to combine the files. That is:

- On the Data tab
- Get & Transform Data
- Get Data
- From File
- From Folder
- Then follow the wizard.

Comment: "Follow the wizard" 4000 times? That doesn't sound very fast.

Comment: @Variatus the wizard will load all 4000 files in the folder (and, optionally, sub-folders) in one step.